# Blog post images are not showing in frontend

Tags: php, wordpress

I have uploaded image from add media and inserted into the post but it is not showing in the front end. I have installed wordpress 3.5.1 and using woocommerce theme. Please give any suggestion.

Comment: view source on the images and make sure that there are images where wordpress is asking for them from.

Comment: could not get your suggestion please can you clarify?

Comment: in your browser go to edit>view source or right click and select view source. track down one of the images that is missing in the html code. Then in your ftp client go and look to see if there is an image where the html says there should be

Comment: I have checked it by using firebug but see only the post text is there but no image tag, but from admin it is showing